# Arch Linux - No output on DisplayPort until I run startx

Tags: archlinux, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, a 27" primary monitor on the middle and a small 17" (I think) monitor to the right. Until now, I've been using the 27" with the HDMI port from my GPU, the GTX 1660 Ti. Now, I bought a display port and I'm using that for the 27" monitor and connected the HDMI to the small monitor.

I don't plan to always use the second monitor, so I keep it turned off. It's only when I do multitasking intensive stuff, I turn it on. However there's a problem.

When I turn on my desktop, there's no output on the display port. It's all going to the HDMI, the small monitor. This goes all the way from the boot passphrase to the motherboard logo, the arch linux loading text, the login and the console terminal. It's only when I run startx, the display port gets a signal. How can I swap this around if possible? Or do I have to disconnect the HDMI all together and only plug it if I need the second monitor?

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 818mm x 1073mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1360x768      60.02* 
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.94  
   720x480       59.94    59.94  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Did you try `xrandr` or its UI `arandr`?